# How to list out array data in firestore for flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi anyone know how to display the data in the array from firestore as a list for flutter?[image]

Comment: First you would read to get the documents from the collection. Here is the documentation from Firebase on that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection. Then you would need to convert that array to widgets. Here is a Flutter Cookbook on that: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/mixed-list#1-create-a-data-source-with-different-types-of-items

Comment: Hi do u find how to get an array element